# NoMethodError: undefined method `define_instance_method'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am trying to define an instance method on Foo, how do I do that, I keep getting method undefined errors for define_method and `define_instance_method`?
Also, why would I use `define_method` vs `define_instance_method`?

```
class Foo
  def boo
    self.instance_variable_set('@a', "help")  # => "help"
  end                                         # => :boo

  def voo
     self.instance_variable_get('@a')  # => "help"
  end                                  # => :voo

 def noo
   define_method 'goo' do  # ~> NoMethodError: undefined method `define_method' for #<Foo:0x00007fce1309e000 @a="help">\nDid you mean?  define_singleton_method
     "goo"
   end
 end                       # => :noo

 def woo
   define_instance_method 'qoo' do  # ~> NoMethodError: undefined method `define_instance_method' for #<Foo:0x00007feacb98e780 @a="help">\nDid you mean?  define_singleton_method
     "qoo"
   end
 end                                # => :woo

end  # => :woo
```

Answer (score 3):

There's `Module#define_method` and there's `Object#define_singleton_method`. There is no `#define_instance_method`.

`Module#define_method` allows you to define an instance method on the receiving module or class, which is analogous to a `def`:

```rb
class A
  def foo
    123
  end
end

A.define_method(:bar) { 456 }

A.new.foo # => 123
A.new.bar # => 456
```

You cannot use it on other type of objects, such as instances of `A`, which are of type `A`, only on `Module` or `Class`:

```rb
A.new.define_method(:bogus) { 'oops' }
# => NoMethodError (undefined method `define_method' for #<A:0x00007ffa6c0c77e0>)
```

`Object#define_singleton_method`, on the other hand, can be used on any `Object`, including `Class` and `Module`. It allows you to create a method on the receiver. For a class or module, that's equivalent to defining a class method:

```rb
class B
  def self.x
    'x'
  end

  class << self
    def y
      'y'
    end
  end
end

B.define_singleton_method(:z) { 'z' }

B.x # => 'x'
B.y # => 'y'
B.z # => 'z'
```

But we can also use it directly on an instance of a class to add a method to that very instance:

```rb
class C; end
c = C.new
c.define_singleton_method(:foo) { 'hello' }
c.foo # => 'hello'
C.new.foo # => NoMethodError (undefined method `foo' for #<C:0x00007ff95f0e4038>)
C.foo # => NoMethodError (undefined method `foo' for C:Class)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Module#define_method` is a private method and also a class method.Your one didn't work,as you tried to call it on the instance of foo class.You have to call it like this:

```
class Foo

 def noo
   self.class.send(:define_method,'goo') { puts 'Goo'}
 end

end
```